# create a new data frame with existing ones

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following data frames

```
treatmet1<-data.frame(id=c(1,2,7))
treatment2<-data.frame(id=c(3,7,10))
control<-data.frame(id=c(4,5,8,9))
```

I want to create a new data frame that is the union of those 3 and have an indicator column that takes the value 1 for each one.

```
experiment<-data.frame(id=c(1:10),treatment1=0, treatment2=0, control=0)
```

where `experiment$treatment1[1]=1` etc etc

What is the best way of doing this in R?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updated as per @ Flodel:

```
    kk<-rbind(treatment1,treatment2,control)
    var1<-c("treatment1","treatment2","control")
    kk$df<-rep(var1,c(dim(treatment1)[1],dim(treatment2)[1],dim(control)[1]))
 kk

    id         df
1   1 treatment1
2   2 treatment1
3   7 treatment1
4   3 treatment2
5   7 treatment2
6  10 treatment2
7   4    control
8   5    control
9   8    control
10  9    control
```

If you want  in the form of 1 and 0 , you can use `table`

```
ll<-table(kk)
ll


  df
id   control treatment1 treatment2
  1        0          1          0
  2        0          1          0
  3        0          0          1
  4        1          0          0
  5        1          0          0
  7        0          1          1
  8        1          0          0
  9        1          0          0
  10       0          0          1
```

If you want it as a data.frame, then you can use `reshape`:

```
kk2<-reshape(data.frame(ll),timevar = "df",idvar = "id",direction = "wide")

names(kk2)[-1]<-sort(var1)
> kk2
 kk2
  id control treatment1 treatment2
1  1       0          1          0
2  2       0          1          0
3  3       0          0          1
4  4       1          0          0
5  5       1          0          0
6  7       0          1          1
7  8       1          0          0
8  9       1          0          0
9 10       0          0          1
```

Comment: +1. Given that they're mutually exclusive, the first form (`kk`) seems like the place to start.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but there is a minor typo in this solution. names(kk2)[-1]<-c("treat1","treat2","cont") should be names(kk2)[-1]<-c("cont","treat1","treat2"). Other than that, this is the faster solution to my problem.

Comment: @Metrics, you shouldn't have to retype the variable names three times, especially if there are many as the OP has now told us. Your code could start with `vars <- c("treatment1", "treatment2", "control")` then use that everywhere. Functions that should come handy are `do.call`, `mget`, `sapply`, `nrow`, `sort`.

Comment: @ flodel: Thanks for the suggestion. I can't use `vars` here since the `table` function sorts the variables.

Comment: sure you can, that's why I mentioned `sort`.

Comment: That's better but in the end, you shouln't be typing "treatment1" and others more than once. You've taken that count from four to three, there are two more to go.

Answer (score 3):

```
df.bind <- function(...) {

  df.names <- all.names(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
  ids.list <- setNames(lapply(list(...), `[[`, "id"), df.names)
  num.ids  <- max(unlist(ids.list))
  tabs     <- lapply(ids.list, tabulate, num.ids)

  data.frame(id = seq(num.ids), tabs)
}

df.bind(treatment1, treatment2, control)

#    id treatment1 treatment2 control
# 1   1          1          0       0
# 2   2          1          0       0
# 3   3          0          1       0
# 4   4          0          0       1
# 5   5          0          0       1
# 6   6          0          0       0
# 7   7          1          1       0
# 8   8          0          0       1
# 9   9          0          0       1
# 10 10          0          1       0
```

(Notice how it does include a row for `id == 6`.)

Comment: if I want to make this parallel i just need to change lapply for mclapply? I have a lot more than 10 observations.

Comment: If you have a lot more than 10 data.frames, I'd recommend you learn about storing your data efficiently before jumping into complex things like parallel processing. Here, typing `df.bind(var1, var2, ..., var25)` is going to be cumbersome as you can imagine. (BTW telling us that detail from the beginning might have been useful.) Instead of many data.frames polluting your environment, you should have one list containing all 25 variables like my `ids.list` does. If you could tell us how you came to create these data.frames, we might help show you how to create `ids.list` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Taking

```
treatment1<-data.frame(id=c(1,2,7))
treatment2<-data.frame(id=c(3,7,10))
control<-data.frame(id=c(4,5,8,9))
```

You can use this:

```
x <- c("treatment1", "treatment2", "control")
f <- function(s) within(get(s), assign(s, 1))
r <- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,all=TRUE), lapply(x, f))
r[is.na(r)] <- 0
```

Result:

```
> r
  id treatment1 treatment2 control
1  1          1          0       0
2  2          1          0       0
3  3          0          1       0
4  4          0          0       1
5  5          0          0       1
6  7          1          1       0
7  8          0          0       1
8  9          0          0       1
9 10          0          1       0
```

Comment: This really seemed more like an `rbind` sort of problem.

Comment: @DWin how to use `rbind` here without calling `table` next?

Comment: I'll post my understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This illustrates what I was imagining to be the `rbind` strategy:

```
alldf <- rbind(treatmet1,treatment2,control)
alldf$grps <- model.matrix( ~ factor( c( rep(1,nrow(treatmet1)),
                                            rep(2,nrow(treatment2)),
                                            rep(3,nrow(control) ) ))-1)
dimnames( alldf[[2]])[2]<- list(c("trt1","trt2","ctrl"))
 alldf
#-------------------
   id grps.trt1 grps.trt2 grps.ctrl
1   1         1         0         0
2   2         1         0         0
3   7         1         0         0
4   3         0         1         0
5   7         0         1         0
6  10         0         1         0
7   4         0         0         1
8   5         0         0         1
9   8         0         0         1
10  9         0         0         1
```

Comment: Seems rather baroque. :-)

Comment: Tastes may differ. I think in comparison with your solution that is much easier to grasp. I'm just stacking dataframes on tp of each other than then making a set of dummies with model matrix to the specifications of the OP, ... plus it does not distort the ordering of the ID variable.

Comment: well, it's definitely not what the OP is after: he wants duplicated ids to be merged. He also wants a row for `id == 6` in spite of it not appearing in any of the inputs.

Comment: Your efforts to conduct mind-reading are "definitely" yielding different results than mine. The notion of "union" might be ambiguous, and I think the code offered was also an ambiguous pseudo-R effort. Hence my reason for thinking there is nothing "definite" in this question.